# Time quantization

Tags: classical-mechanics, time, calculus, discrete

There is no evidence to support that time is quantized. So wouldn't the use of discrete values like $dt$ in calculus suggest time is quantized and comes in discrete durations of $dt$?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111611/discussion-on-question-by-blue5000-time-quantization).

Comment: What qualifies as "extended discussion" ?

Comment: It's an autogenerated comment so don't read too much into that wording, but off the top of my head if an exchange reaches more than four comments we'll probably at least think about moving it. If it looks like it's about to wrap up within the next few comments, we might leave it, but otherwise there's a decent chance of it getting migrated to chat. Of course it's always a case-by-case determination based on several factors, and I'd encourage asking on [meta] if you want a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The use of $dt$ is precisely to avoid discrete time. Suppose speed  of something at time $t$ equals $t^2$. This scenario clearly involves a continuously changing speed. What we could do to calculate the approximate distance the particle travels from $t=0$ to $t=1$ is:

Divide the interval $t=0$ to 1 into, say, 100 smaller intervals, and assume the speed to be constant throughout each interval.

So the approximate distance traveled in the first 0.01 seconds= speed*time=$0^2*0.01$

In the next 0.01 seconds = $0.01^2*0.01$
.....

In the last 0.01 seconds=$(0.99^2*0.01)$

And finally we could add up these distances.

But the above calculation doesn't exactly capture the continuously changing nature of the speed. It assumes speed to be constant in small finite intervals.

So instead, what we actually do is calculate the limit of the distanced traveled as we make this interval smaller and smaller (the $h \to 0$ in calculus). That's what the integration method achieves (when you calculate $\int_0 ^1 t^2 dt$). It perfectly captures what would've happened if speed was changing continuously.

Comment: When this integral is done there are other terms that go to zero as you say. these get left out of the result t^3/3 and intern are left out of the value of 1/3 for t=1 t=0 , however if the value of dt is not zero then no matter how small these extra terms become that is no excuse to exclude them from the final result.

Comment: Some formatting hints: $h\to0$ can be entered as `$h\to0$`; multiplication can be typeset as $\times$ via `$\times$` or as $a\cdot b$ via `$a\cdot b$`.

Comment: @Blue5000 in the limit they are zero: $$\lim\limits_{x\to0}x=0.$$

Comment: I have seen this before , but what exactly do you mean by "in the limit" ?

Comment: @Blue5000 On the calculator, you can try calculating $\int_0^1 t^2 dt$ by dividing the interval $t=0$ to $1$ into smaller and smaller subintervals (and assuming the speed to be constant throughout each subinterval). You'd find that you can make the distance traveled as close to $\frac{1}{3}$ as you want if you only increase the number of sub-intervals (this can be proved too). So we say that $\frac{1}{3}$ is the limit of the distance traveled as the number of sub-intervals tends to infinity

Comment: @Ruslan I can't see the edit option for some reason

Comment: +1 for the first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

No. The use of "dt" in calculus has no correspondence with the passage of time in the physical world; it is a mathematical construct.

Comment: "any slice of time shorter than the Planck time (10^-43 second) has no physical meaning", can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: But doesn't dt represent a non zero duration of time ?

Comment: @Blue5000 no, $dt$ is an [infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal).

Comment: If the value of dt is non zero then dt represents a specific time duration .What's the flaw in that logic ?

Comment: @nielsnielsen There is no widely-accepted theory in which times shorter than the Planck time have no physical meaning. You are (reasonably) presupposing what some eventually-accepted theory of quantum gravity will say about time.

Comment: When you take the first derivative of say v=t^2 you obtain dv/dt = 2t but     dv/dt = 2t+dt.  dt is said to go to zero but I'm finding this extremely hard to comprehend as by definition dt is not zero. Is it just not the case that dt is so insignificantly small no apparatus would be able to detect such a small duration of time

Comment: @G.Smith, I am quoting from physlink. Is this idea in error?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei, source = physlink, will look for more info from other sources. -NN

Comment: @G.Smith, Will edit out reference to planck time. -NN

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei, will edit out reference to planck time. -NN

Comment: @Blue5000 dt does not represent a specific time duration, and that is its point.  It is part of a limit expression "*where dt approaches zero*".  We call it an "infinitesimal" which just means that it's a trick to use something that both is and is not actually zero in equations where we cannot use zero (because everything would reduce down to expressions of the form *0/0*).  So because 0/0 is mathematically undefined/indeterminate we use dt as "arbitrarily close to zero, but not zero" to see what values/expressions our dx/dt expressions converge to as dt approaches zero.

Comment: We also use dt in integration to get around the reciprocal problem: we have to sum an infinite number of infinitesimally small things.  But infinity times zero is also undefined/indeterminate  so we replace zero with "as dt approaches zero" and we replace the Sigma sign (summation) with the Integral sign to mean (approaches an infinite summation as dt approaches zero).  And this is all a set of mathematical originally applied to Newtonian physics (by Newton himself) long before Quantum Mechanics came along. It has nothing to do with whether physical time is quantum or not.

Comment: Yes they converge to a value as dt approaches zero but my point is dt will never actually be zero so the convergence value will never be that value only arbitrarily close. And I don't think it's actually arbitrarily because it's a value that's not zero however close it is to zero

Comment: @Blue5000  No.  Again, this is all a mathematical trick to defer the equations from reducing to 0/0 just so that we can see where dx/dt is converging to.  It has nothing to do with quantums, and in fact it specifically assumes that it's range (the Real numbers) are infinitely continuous.  The whole trick wouldn't work in a discrete range like the integers (where it also wouldn't be needed). This is mathematics, *not physics*.

Comment: The thing is that _dt_ is not a value. It is part of the notation of the derivative or integral, and has no meaning on its own. If you want to see the actual value that has a non-zero value, but becomes arbitrarily small as the limit goes to zero, you have to expand the derivative or integral into its limit-based definition, in which the value becomes visible. With the derivative, that small but non-zero value is typically denoted with a _h_, and not _dt_.

Answer (score 2):

Though time maybe continuous, you can discretize time into small intervals to solve the problem. This is how we solve differential equations numerically. But i think you mean to question the exact results obtained by calculus. This is valid because if we can discretize time much smaller than least count of our apparatus that measures time, these 'exact results' show correct answers inside the error margin. Also, it's important to note that when we solve a physics problem, we idealise and make it into a mathematical problem. In physics, we assume that time is continuous. If time is indeed quantised, the "exact" results obtained by idealising are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you encounter things such as $dx$ or $dt$, you have to understand that these do not represent actual values that you can talk about on their own. They are merely part of a larger notation. For example, with a derivative, the thing that has a meaning is the entire fraction itself:
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} $$
If you evaluated this fraction in the point $t_1$, its value is defined to be
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x(t_1 + h) - x(t_1)}{h}
$$
So, the value that is going to zero is the $h$ in the expression above. And indeed, $h$ is some nonzero real number.

---

In physics you will very often see $dx$ and $dt$ being on their own, usually on either side of an equality sign, but mathematically speaking, this is incorrect and in fact meaningless. They *have* to be part of either a derivative or integral, and they are just part of the notation of how you write down a derivative or integral, just like the notation for a fraction includes a straight line, which has no meaning on its own.

The reason it always works when you separate them like that is because limits can be exchanged with most operations, i.e. you can exchange the order of taking the limit with everything from addition and multiplication, to literally any other continuous function. This means that once you put them back together, you get the same results as if you had worked rigorously with limits.

(there are [some ways](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/25/ultrafilters-nonstandard-analysis-and-epsilon-management/) to rigorously give them a value, but those values would not act like ordinary real numbers do, because they are not real numbers)

Comment: When $dx,dy$ etc. stand alone then most of the times they are viewed as differential forms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form). These are perfectly rigorous.